# Why does my Javascript break in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

The following code breaks in IE8:

```
getTypes: function (filter) {
    features = []
    _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
        _.each(item.get(filter), function (value) {
            if(features.indexOf(value) == -1){ //// error happens here
                features.push(value)
            }
        })
    })
    return features
}
```

I get the error message:
**Message: Object doesn't support this property or method**

http://jsfiddle.net/w8fm2bf1/

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IE versions  before IE9 does not support [.indexOf() function for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

As an alternative you can use [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). Something like this:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(val) {
        return jQuery.inArray(val, this);
    };
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to read and answer. Could you confirm, I should use something like this `if(features.inArray(value) == -1){ features.push(value)  }` ?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk:- Give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.indexOf` isn't supported in IE until version 9. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)).

You'll need to monkey patch it (there's an example on the MDN page linked above) or use an alternative.

Comment: OP, note that there's a polyfill at the bottom of that page you can use for non-compliant browsers.